# Android EditText : close keyboard when return button is clicked

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've managed to prevent my edit text from showing the keyboard when the view is entered. Now it only shows when I tap on it, this thanks to this line in my manifest (in the block dedicated to the corresponding activity) :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Now I'm having the following problem, when I click the return button it doesn't hide the keyboard. What should I do ? Thanks.

**EDIT** : finally I solved it by adding `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` in my xml layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yoi can use `hideSoftInputFromWindow(....)` by supplying the edittext window and force the keyboard to be hidden.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) link.It will help you.